# Does mobile 6 phones generate a .dll?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-mobile, nunit

I want to grab the .dll from a mobile phone application I am making since I want to add it to my nunit so I can write & test my application. Yet I don't see any .dll in the bin folder. How do I unit test it?

Comment: What kind of application are you making? Have you checked the deployment path in Visual Studio?

Comment: how many projects do you have in your solution?

Comment: I just have one project in my solution. I am making an simple application with a couple textboxes that will connect to a web service.

Comment: Like I have only 2 things in my bin folder -> debug folder. Application and Program debug database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are compiling an application (EXE) then no, there is no DLL.  If you want a DLL, you have to create a DLL project.

Comment: I see. So what do I do if I want to unit test my phone application then?

Comment: I'm not certain about nunit, but since managed assemblies are all loadable via reflection then it should be able to load and test the methods just like it does with DLLs.  That's how mstest works.  If that doesn't work, break the logic into a DLL that you can test.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit should be able to look at the EXE and run tests against that exe.